# Word 2011: Hiding / unhiding objects

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I would like to hide an object in **Word 2011** (e.g., Logo), to print without logo on preprinted paper and print with logo for digital use. I am working both with Windows and Mac versions. In Word 2010 (Windows) this can be done via the selection pane. **Where do I find the selection pane in Word 2011?**. It does not seem to be present in Word 2011.

A work around is in preferences: to print / not to print drawing objects, but this option hides objects which do not need to be hided...and refers to the Word preferences and not to document settings.

Comment: How can what you asked in your question title be done using the selection pane?

Comment: @adam When I go to the selection pane in WORD 2010, I can check/uncheck visibility of objects. Easy, but seems not to be available in WORD 2011, mac.

Comment: AFAIK (a) there is no equivalent on Mac Word, (b) even to hide an image, you will probably have to select it and use a bit of VBA (like Selection.Shapes(1).Visible = False) and making them visible once hidden is harder (because it is either difficult or impossible to make a selection that will contain the shape).

Comment: if (b) is meant for Word 2010 >  in selection pane, You have a clear overview which objects/shapes are hidden/not visible. No need for VBA.

Comment: No, I was talking about the Mac version for a,b and c.

Comment: You could also consider an IF field which tests the print datetime compared to the current datetime and displays the image based on that.